# What tool would this handle be for?

Tags: hand-tools, tool-identification

I was at LeeValley at the clearance section because I remember the last time I was there they had some cheap totes. I was flipping through the bin and found a couple that I could use.

While I was looking I found a few handles that I could not place as totes for planes. Your standard plane totes are flat on the bottom for where they meet the body. These however are curved on both ends.

The following picture shows two such handles side by side. One shows the top while the other shows the bottom.

[image]

<sup>Image from my phone!</sup>

It must be for a plane but I can't figure out which one? For that reason I am hesitenet to use [plane](/questions/tagged/plane)

Comment: You should probably have asked the store staff. I agree that the shape looks wrong for any plane I can think of right now, but planes aren't the only tools that use wooden handles of this sort.

Comment: It's not a saw handle either....It would fit on the end of a tool.... The place was packed with people since it is Christmas time. That and I though it would be more fun to ask here. I am _assuming_ plane but it none of the ones I can think of.

Comment: I'd just like to say that I'm super jealous you have a LV store near you.  They don't have them in the States just yet.

Comment: @grfrazee You have _way_ better access to flea markets then I do. Lee Valley is too high end for my needs right now. I like finding cheap tools.

Comment: I suppose that's true.  Flea market picking is one of my favorite pastimes.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not that familiar with new-build tools but that looked naggingly familiar and I was relatively sure it was for a saw and not any sort of plane. This made it easy to track down:

[image: Veritas dovetail saw attachment]

[Veritas dovetail saw]

Edit: it looks like the handle is common to their tenon saw as well even though it features a slightly different means of attachment:

[image: Veritas tenon saw]

[Veritas tenon saw]

Comment: That's got to be it. Well done! (I've heard good things about those saws. Then again, I've heard very few complaints about anything in the Veritas product line except that they ain't cheap in _either_ sense of the word.

Comment: Note that the photo also demonstrates proper grip for most saws.

Comment: I was "so sure" that it was not a saw.... Good work.

Comment: I have a Veritas carcass saw, immediately recognized the tote and was about to post, but you beat me to it by almost a full day!

Comment: Yep.  Knew it right off, but you beat me to it.  Also, FWIW, those handles are usually made of bubinga.